# Can viewing your own question cause its view count to increase?

Tags: discussion, views

Does viewing my own question cause its view count to increase?

I've noticed that whenever I view the question, it always seems that, coincidentally, the view count has gone up by one, as if doing so were based on my own previous viewing of it.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273220/578411

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 21):

A question view is stored in a expiring cache using the user number and the question number or, in case of anonymous (non-registered/non-authenticated) users, it uses the IP address (instead of user number) and the question number.

Since this cache keeps information for about 15 minutes, all hits the question receives beyond the first from the same user or IP will not count towards the views. As soon as that time passes and the cache expires, hits from those users or IPs will again be taken into account.

So yes, you viewing your own question causes its view count to increase but only once in more or less 15 minutes.

All information used in this answer was valid at 2014-04-23, the relevant process could then have changed.

Source: this [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/280467) on Meta Stack Exchange.