# Does the question view count refer to members only?

Tags: support, views

I was wondering if the question viewed count refers to any internet user (not necessarily a Stack Overflow member) or if it is just a Stack Overflow users view count.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question view count is IP based (within a time limit - so refreshes don't immediately increment it).

In other words - "the question viewed count is any internet user".

Comment: @Oded..So, if same user view a question multiple times does it increase view count??

Comment: @PraveenMitta: yes, but limited by time and ip address. If two people from the same IP address view within a short time window, one view is counted. If a person comes back later on, and views again, then another view is counted.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the time limit? One of the question i asked in SO had 937 view count yesterday and i revisited same question today and view count is still the same 937

Comment: I would also like to know what the time limit is.

Comment: There is a de facto standard on the web advertising market, what counts as a "unique visit". As far I can remember, maybe it is a page hit from a unique IP, only once per hour (the numbers may differ but that is the essence). Possibly the SE follows / tries to follow this.