# How does the page view count work on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, views, anonymous-user

Does the view count increase if I visit a question without logging in?

For example, a question has 300 views and 5 visitors with different IP addresses visit it without logging in. Will the view count be increased (to 305) in this case?

Comment: The question view count is IP based within a time limit. And yes 5 visiters With diffrent IP addresses visit it without logging in then it will increase to 305.

Comment: Check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273218/does-the-question-view-count-refer-to-members-only?rq=1).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your view count will be increased.

It does not depend on whether a user is logged in or not. If any new user or non-user of SO visits your question, then the view count will be increased.

However, anonymous users must have different IP addresses to be counted.