# Why are questions starting with 1 view?

Tags: bug, questions, views

Why does every question start with 1 view?

I suspect that it is my view, and if that's true, why does the system count my view on my own question?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You _are_ viewing the page don't you?

Comment: @Ivar But it's obvious that I will see my own question, non?

Comment: I'd say so. But I don't see any reason why that wouldn't count as a view.

Comment: you can give it 4 views in one hour by refreshing the page every 15 minutes. Views are counted per IP. IP addresses are kept for 15 minutes. You posting the question leads to a GET. That logs your IP and therefor counts as a view.

Comment: There is probably someone else with you on the same room looking at your screen.

Comment: @rene One could specifically look at non-closed question with a low view count (say <10), might be if nobody else was looking that people still need help or to vote at least a bit.

Comment: Did you ask yourself "why not?" first? It is a helpful tool to write more complete questions. If you can answer that question then perfect, you can add the reasoning to the meta question to provide more background. If you cannot think of a single reason, even far fetched, why not... well then maybe there isn't even a reason to ask the question. But if you must ask because you lack faith in your own reasoning skills, then you can at least confess that so people know where the question is coming from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know, some askers are diligent about preparing and maintaining their questions.

If system disqualified their views, they would probably complain,

> <sup>How come that my question shows zero views? I myself went to it right after pressing Post button to see how it would look for other readers and re-check if maybe I made some mistakes that somehow missed when I prepared it, or maybe final rendering deviated from what I saw in preview for some reason. Therefore it looks unfair to ignore my view.</sup>

And there's one more thing worth knowing, initially system was designed to assume good intent (once upon a time it was even [stated in Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335026/165773)).

And because of that I think it is natural that system made choice in favor of such diligent, well intentioned askers (assuming they are all like that), and dismissed the possibility that somebody may just dump their stuff into question box and immediately drop off without even attempting to re-check how it looks like for other readers.

Comment: this is probably related: [Can viewing your own question cause its view count to increase?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262802/839601)