# I created a private team, my private question was viewed 10 times before I added users

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, views

I created a private team

I asked the first private question.

Before I added any users to my team, the question was viewed 10 times.

How can this be? Is my team not really private?

Comment: How often did you visit or reload the question page? 10 times?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz view should be per IP/user, no? also not every reload increase count

Comment: @ user7294900  this restriction got removed when SE switched from http to https

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated)

Comment: @yivi it increase more then 1 after revisiting, I don't think it's the case/full picture

Comment: Related: *[Increase question views once per user in a private team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412078)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every view of a question on a private team increments the view counter. Including your own views, including multiple views from the same user, including multiple views in quick sequence. This is different behavior than the [way that it works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262802/can-viewing-your-own-question-cause-its-view-count-to-increase) on the Public Platform.

I assume that you viewed your question 10 times.

Comment: Not every refresh increase count, Behavior is very strange and not consistent , I wonder if this can be fixed in feature request/enhancement

Comment: @user7294900 Almost definitely caching at work there.