# Increase question views once per user in a private team

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, views

In Teams, views of the user who posted the question sometimes [increase the question's view count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412072/6045800):

> Every view of a question on a private team increments the view counter. Including your own views, including multiple views from the same user, including multiple views in quick sequence.

(Not every refresh increases the count.)

It looks very strange in a private team.

- Can views of the user who posted the question be ignored as question views in a private team?
- Can views be even per user? I.e., every view of user1234 will be treated as one view?

Answer (score 6):

I can't answer for the Teams Team but I personally like that we count views more than once ever. That said, I prefer the standard on public sites where we only increment the count after a 15-minute cool-down. There's value in seeing how many times a post is viewed even if one person views it multiple times - perhaps it's a commonly-referenced question and you get to see that in the views.

If it's only ever once per person the number will max out at the count of people on the team, which is... of limited value and kinda boring. If you have 20 people on the Team, you'd know if everyone viewed the question but it wouldn't tell you if it was a frequently-referenced question.

Comment: Also, counting "views per unique user" would also require adding a table and a check on every request. And keep track of all "posts viewed" by a single user, which is kinda creepy. Personally, if I had to implement it, I'd simply decline on the grounds that too much work and possible headaches for too little value.

Comment: I understand the reason why one person may increase view count several times (in a wide date range). But I can't understand why simply [refreshing the page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413456/3240681) allows me to increase the view count by 3 and then stops. Why not just one (1) new view per user in an hour for instance? If it stops on 3 then there is some code for it already, just change 3 to 1.