# Views counter in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, views

I'm the only one member of my free Stack Overflow for Teams team. Right after asking the question I can refresh the page and see how views counter rise up to 2, 3, 4 and stops growing. I know that some time later (days?) I can (re)visit the same page and the visited counter will be increased.

But for what reason, even after the post creation, can I rise up the views counter by myself to 4?

It turns out that already after ~50 minutes (not days) I can refresh a page and rise the views count to 7.

Comment: This linked question is a feature request, not a support question, but it does contain an answer, which mentions that it's an intentional decision: [Increase question views once per user in a private team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412078/increase-question-views-once-per-user-in-a-private-team)